# Creating new array with variables coming back as undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am creating a blog web application. I currently have the blogSchema set up as

```
var BlogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   title: String,
   image: String,
   body: String,
   created: 
         {type: Date, default: Date.now},
   author: {
      id: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "User"
      },
      username: String
   },
   comments: [
      {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "Comment"
      }
   ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Blog", BlogSchema);
```

I have a post form of the following

```
<div class="ui main text container segment">
    <div class="ui huge header">New Blog</div>
    <form class="ui form" action="/blogs" method="POST">
        <div class="field">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="blog[title]" placeholder="title">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Image</label>
            <input type="text" name="blog[image]" placeholder="image">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Blog Content</label>
            <textarea name="blog[body]"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input class="ui violet big basic button" type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

On my blog routes page I have my create route as

```
router.post("/blogs", function(req, res){
    // create blog
    //req.body.blog.body = req.sanitize(req.body.blog.body);
    var title = req.body.title;
    var image = req.body.image;
    var desc  = req.body.body;
    var author= {
        id: req.user._id,
        username: req.user.username
    }
    var newBlogpost = {title: title, image: image, body: desc, author: author}
    Blog.create(newBlogpost, function(err, newBlog){
        if(err){
            res.render("blogs/new");
        } else {
            //then, redirect to the index
            console.log(newBlogpost)
            res.redirect("/blogs");
        }
    });
});
```

However when I sign in on the web application and complete the form and view my commmand line for the return of console.log(newBlogpost) after I submit, I get:

```
{ title: undefined,
  image: undefined,
  body: undefined,
  author: { id: 5a0cbcc3d6c7070a7bb6c45e, username: 'cat' }
```

I am not sure why the new variable array I am creating has these three variable as undefinded and would appreciate help.

Comment: Have you verified `req.body` has content? You may not be [parsing](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions) it.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I am trying to create a new post and I get the error message, Cannot read property 'body' of undefined

Comment: The easiest way would be to add `console.log( req.body );` at the very beginning of your route. [Mozilla has a pretty good tutorial that is somewhat similar to what you are trying to do.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/forms)

Comment: I added it a console.lg(req.body) and it is returning values for title, image and body, it seems the issues that I having is when I include the author variable and try to combine all of them into a one variable

Comment: You can try changing the name of the input tags from `name="blog[title]"` to `name="title"`.